# How do I listen for a user exit in my Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an Eclipse plugin for a college project and need to be able to run code when the user exits and I can't find the correct Listener to enable me do this. An example of similar code is shown below where I listen for successfully completed save events and call a method when this occurs.

```
public class ExecutionListener implements IExecutionListener{

private DataCollector dataCollector;

public ExecutionListener(DataCollector dataCollector)
{
    this.dataCollector = dataCollector;
}

public void postExecuteSuccess(String action, Object arg1) 
{
    if (action.equals("org.eclipse.ui.file.save")) {
        dataCollector.writeDatabase();
    }
}
```

So what I want is a Listener which will allow me to listen for exit events and call a method to run my code when this happens. I suppose I wont be able to ensure the exit is successfully completed before running the code but a 'pre-exit' Listener would work just fine. Also if someone does know of the correct Listener could they also tell me the commandId I will need for the exit event (e.g. the commandId for the save event in the above example is "org.eclipse.ui.file.save").

Thanks, Jacob

EDIT: To reply to javamonkey79's question:

I add the listener like this:

```
/* Adds a listener to listen for file save events if needed. */
if (executionListener == null) {
    ICommandService service = (ICommandService) Activator.getDefault().getWorkbench().
    getService(ICommandService.class);
    executionListener = new ExecutionListener();
    service.addExecutionListener(executionListener);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515993/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-a-shutdown-hook-for-an-eclipse-rcp-application/671532

Comment: The reffered question, which I asked, is reared to a different problem.  Namely how to detect that the JVM is being shut down in an irregular manner.  For example, as a result of a forced operating system shutdown.

Comment: How did you add this listener?

Comment: It's javamonkey 79 not 29, but upvoted for the edit & response - thank you vm :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Activator class of your plugin contains a stop() method.  The Activator is the class in your plugin that extends the Plugin class and that is referenced in the Manifest.MF at the "Bundle-Activator" tag.  [The OSGi documentation contains a description on the plugin lifecycle.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-osgi/index.html)

When the workspace is closed, all of the plugins are stopped.  You can then add any clean-up code that you require in this section.

```
public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    plugin = null;
            // Code to clean up here...

    super.stop(context);
}
```

[The API describes when this method is called](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Plugin.html).  Interesting snippet from the API:

> Note 1: If a plug-in has been
>   automatically started, this method
>   will be automatically invoked by the
>   platform when the platform is shut
>   down.

The advantages of using this method instead of using a listener on the UI, is that you know that it will be called regardless of how the user leaves the workspace.

Comment: Is this called if the plugin supplies a builder and the builder hasn't finished yet?  I'd like to allow the user to cancel my builder if and only if shutdown has been requested (canceling leaves a library in an unstable state, and I don't control the library code, so I can't fix that).