# press x on top right corner Event for eclipse-rcp

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am working on an eclipse-rcp project. I want to implement an EventListener (or something like that), which is called, when the user presses the x on the top right corner of the window.
Any idea where/how I can implement this?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to do so, depending on what you need. If you want to forbid closing of the main shell under some circumstances, you might want to use `preWindowShellClose()` method in your `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`. http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fapplication%2FWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.html .

If you just want to perform some action when main window is closed, you could add a shutdownHook like this (see also this thread: [What is the correct way to add a Shutdown Hook for an Eclipse RCP application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515993/what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-a-shutdown-hook-for-an-eclipse-rcp-application)):

```
    public class IPEApplication implements IApplication {
      public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        final Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new ShutdownHook());  }
        // start workbench...
      }
    }

private class ShutdownHook extends Thread {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
      final Display display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                                        .getDisplay();
      if (workbench != null && !workbench.isClosing()) {
        display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            IWorkbenchWindow [] workbenchWindows = 
                            workbench.getWorkbenchWindows();
            for(int i = 0;i < workbenchWindows.length;i++) {
              IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow =
                                        workbenchWindows[i];
              if (workbenchWindow == null) {
                // SIGTERM shutdown code must access
                // workbench using UI thread!!
              } else {


        IWorkbenchPage[] pages = workbenchWindow
                                       .getPages();
            for (int j = 0; j < pages.length; j++) {
              IEditorPart[] dirtyEditors = pages[j]
                                       .getDirtyEditors();
              for (int k = 0; k < dirtyEditors.length; k++) {
                dirtyEditors[k]
                         .doSave(new NullProgressMonitor());
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
    display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        workbench.close();
      }
    });
  }
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  // ignore
}

  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think preWindowShellClose() should work for me. However I can't find the WorkbenchWindowAdvisor Object in my project. Any clue where I can find/create it?

Comment: Try to search for a class which extends WorkbenchWindowAdvisor. When you create your application, in the class which implements IPlatformRunnable, you pass an instance of WorkbenchAdvisor (some thing like that PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());) And in the WorkbenchAdvisor you should override createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) method which create instance of WorkbenchWindowAdwisor you are looking for. Please accept the main answer, if this have helped you.